# Update code in REMOTE debugging?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, remote-debugging

is it possible to perform any changes in code remote debugging?
 (in Debug and Release as well)

Comment: in code remote debbuging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You are debugging an instance of a deployed application on another machine - you can't update the binaries remotely while they're running.